# Problem with excluding a certain direction in a game

Tags: javascript

im struggeling with a implementation on how i my player can only walk in one dierection .... As Example: when player walks in x direction he cant walk in -x direction only in y dierection, the same for y. If he walks for example in -y he cant change to y.

Thanks for any help!
Heres how i switch the direction of my player:

```
 this.changeDirection = function(direction) {
    switch(direction) {
        case "Up":
            this.xSpeed = 0;
            this.ySpeed = -scale;
            break; 
        case "Down":
            this.xSpeed = 0;
            this.ySpeed = scale;
            break; 
        case "Left":
            this.xSpeed = -scale;
            this.ySpeed = 0;
            break; 
        case "Right":
            this.xSpeed = scale;
            this.ySpeed = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You tag this question with css, how this is related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Up` and `Down`, add `if (this.ySpeed === 0)` before each assignment block:

```
case "Up":
    if (this.ySpeed === 0) {
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = -scale;
    }
    break;
```

And do a similar thing for `Left` & `Right`.

Comment: Yea that worked ... huh how didnt i think about that ... haha thanks buddy :)